# Blur effect on view background

Tags: ios, swift

I have this extension, and I was hoping for a blur background, where I can see blur through the view:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

extension UIView
{
    func addBlurEffect()
    {
        if !UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled() {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

            let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light)
            let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
            blurEffectView.frame = self.bounds
            blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        } else {
            self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }

    }
}
```

Then I use it like this:

```
let v = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)

v.addBlurEffect()


self.view.addSubview(v)
```

But I can not see anything under the view?

Comment: Maybe self.view or other view under the view v has a backgroundColor and it´s opaque. Did you check in view inspector?

Comment: I don't get your problem. Works fine.

Comment: @AaronZheng You are so right, it does work :-) I just had two Labels, and that is simply almost not visible for the blur to be seen. After adding a full background image to the ViewController.view I can see the effect. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add [this](https://github.com/xpams/UIView-Blur) framework to your project.

Add transparent view over your background and setup blur (view Readme on github)
[image]
[Preview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFiccUux58M)